# is it possible to have own audio file during call in android programmatically

Tags: android

As i am using TelephonyManager and when its CALL_STATE is OFF_HOOK.

```
 if (null == manager) {
            manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            try {
                // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
                // ITelephony getter
                Log.v("Anviti", "Get getTeleService...");
                Class c = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());
                Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
             //   com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(manager);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Anviti",
                        "FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
                Log.e("Anviti", "Exception object: " + e);
            }
            if(manager.getCallState()==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: your question is not very clear? what you want to try? do you want to play your own audio during a voice call?

Comment: yes, i want to play my own audio during a call.

Comment: you can play your own audio over call audio.but you can not supress call audio. You do not have the control of ongoing call. only thing you can do it listen for different call states.

Answer (score 0):

you can play your own audio over call audio.but you can not suppress call audio. You do not have the control of ongoing call. only thing you can do it listen for various call states.